make picture/image/pixel image of a xml-file
I am trying to write a script to convert my XML files of direct image exoplanet data into/back into images for my AI classifier, but I having some trouble with converting the XML's into images. An example of the input is:
<data><row>
    <name>WISEA J083011.95+283716.0</name>
    <binaryflag>0</binaryflag>
    <mass>8.5</mass>
    <radius />
    <period />
    <semimajoraxis />
    <eccentricity />
    <periastron />
    <longitude />
    <ascendingnode />
    <inclination />
    <temperature>350.0</temperature>
    <age />
    <discoverymethod>imaging</discoverymethod>
    <discoveryyear>2020.0</discoveryyear>
    <lastupdate>21/10/19</lastupdate>
    <system_rightascension>08 30 11.95</system_rightascension>
    <system_declination>+28 37 16.00</system_declination>
    <system_distance>11.1</system_distance>
    <hoststar_mass />
    <hoststar_radius />
    <hoststar_metallicity />
    <hoststar_temperature />
    <hoststar_age />
    <list>Confirmed planets</list>
  </row>
  </data>

When I tried the method I knew, it made an image but it was an image of the input as a table. Is there anyway for it to be transformed into at least a pixel image of the direct imaged exoplanets? What rows are important to translate that information?

When I tried the method I knew, it made an image …
Please share your python code.

You can't conjure an exoplanet image out of a few words and thin air!
(well you can but it would be a spurious "artist's impression" - too many of them about already)
XML convert will turn the XML rendering of the table text into an image but that isn't what you want - you have asked for actual images of the object. You might be able to concoct a script to find them on arXiv but you will likely have to look at each paper it finds in turn to see if it really contains the image(s) you seek.
Or do you already have the image files somewhere in your database and the thing you have presented is just an indexing header? It seems to be lacking a link to binary data.
The XML file contains RA & Dec of the object with enough precision that you might be able to link to the right bit of one of the deep catalogues like Hipparchus or Palomar Sky Survey (more recent ones available).
Or use the object name "WISEA J083011.95+283716.0" which immediately got me this hit in arXiv WISEA J083011.95+283716.0: A Missing Link Planetary-Mass and the unWISE discovery images are on page 6.
SIMBAD is the other obvious place to look and that might do what you want more or less right out of the tin with a bit of cunning web scraping. A combination of the two ought to work fairly well.
I think an AI classifier is going to really struggle on this... faint dots in a CCD image all look very similar.

I appreciate this, yeah I may just have to sleuth through papers to get the best images for my classifier. thank you !

Training it on a series multispectral images of each object might just possibly work. The planets are bright in the thermal bands whereas the stars are not. Good luck with it...
